# Ready event not working as expected

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have tried to implement the ready event handler, basically copying from the Guide however I cannot get it to work.

What am I missing?

```
function drawVisualization() {

    ...
    ...
    ...

    table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table1'));
    table.draw(dataTable, {width: 1100});   

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', resizeTable);
}

function resizeTable() { 
    alert('Will this work?');
}
```

//This code does not produce an alert

Comment: Post all your html and JavaScript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From google docs [about Table events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Events):

**ready**   *The chart is ready for external method calls. If you want to interact with the chart, and call methods after you draw it, you should set up a listener for this event **before** you call the draw method, and call them only after the event was fired.*

So, you have to change order of code to:

```
...
table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table1'));

google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', resizeTable);

table.draw(dataTable, {width: 1100});   
...
```