# Google Annotation Chart zoom button sizes

Tags: button, annotations, google-visualization, size

I have a Google Annotation Chart and I can't figure out how to change the zoom button sizes at the top. They are very small and the font is not ideal either. 
You can see the buttons that I mean here:
[Chart buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2w9G.png)

How can I change their style? Also is there a way to add horizontal lines to the background, the chart currently only has vertical lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select it and make big

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', onReady);

chart.draw(data, options);

function onReady() {
   var x = document.getElementById('chart_div_AnnotationChart_zoomControlContainer').getElementsByTagName('button');
   document.getElementById('chart_div_AnnotationChart_zoomControlContainer').style.fontSize = '14px';

   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.height = '40px';
       x[i].style.width = '40px';
       x[i].style.fontSize = '14px';
   }
}
```

On Google example annotation chart (updated): https://jsfiddle.net/damiantt/upqxj1wb/2/

Comment: I would recommend waiting on the chart's `'ready'` [event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart#events) to fire, before performing any modifications. a chart with real data could take longer to draw, which would cause an error...

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you happen to know where I could find a list containing all the style options for zoomControlContainer? I would also like to change the size of the 'Zoom' text as well as the size of the text in the top right corner.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp zoom size: document.getElementById('chart_div_AnnotationChart_zoomControlContainer').style.fontSize = '14px';

Comment: Actually, I ran into a problem the line 
var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
causes an error when I change the zoom. "a is not a function". I can just press x and it works, but do you know what causes this? 
http://puu.sh/ooZ5e/48d00f0a47.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21812095/5497618 i placed addListener wrong and type onReady() instead onReady . https://jsfiddle.net/damiantt/upqxj1wb/2/